# Help me prove the summation function for $\arcsin x$

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion, pi

Hope you're having a good day. While solving for Maclaurin series for $\arcsin(x)$, I noticed the summation of the series to be:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n-1}((2n-3)!!)^2}{(2n-1)!}.
$$
Since, $\arcsin(0.5) = \pi/6$,

$$6 \arcsin(0.5) = \pi.$$

After substituting $x = 0.5$ and multiplying by $6$, I got

$$
 6\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-1}((2n-3)!!)^2}{(2n-1)!}.
$$

After running the second equation through wolfram alpha to infinty, it shows it as $\pi$.

But, I have no idea how to prove the function. I think it may have to do with binomial theorem but I don't know where to start with the proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: After referring to Thomas Andrew's answer, I've managed to derive the equation

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!!x^{2n+1}}{(2n)!!(2n+1)}
$$

Which gives the same result as the first equation.

I've also noticed in the equation to find pi, taking

$$
\pi = 24\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!!\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}^{2n+1}}{(2n)!!(2n+1)}
$$

Which gives a convergence rate of approcimately 18 digits of pi per 10 iterations

The speed of convergence increases with decrease in the value of x, which is an improvement over the first equation.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "I have no idea how to prove the function"? Are you trying to prove that the Maclaurin series you've given above is correct?

Comment: So are you trying to prove that $$\pi =
 6\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-1}((2n-3)!!)^2}{(2n-1)!}
$$ *without* using the Mc Laurin series for $\arcsin x$?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to prove that the summation function for arcsinx is valid till infinity. I have solved for maclaurin's series upto the 10th function only and got the summation for arcsinx based on observing the maclaurin seies.

Comment: @vitamin d , i ran the function through wolfram alpha and it gave me pi. The first summation series is based on maclaurin series

Comment: Yeah, replies, like mine, since deleted, were confused by “found.” “Found” here can mean you’ve shown it, or it can mean you just found the formula in a book or on some site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if $f(x)=\arcsin x$ then for $$f’(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$$

Then we write (by the general binomial theorem):

$$f’(x)=(1-x^2)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}x^{2n}$$

Then you need to find a different form for $(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}n$ and then integrate the resulting series to get a series for $f(x).$

Specifically, $$\begin{align}\binom{-1/2}{n}&=(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n n!}\\&=(-1)^n\frac{((2n-1)!!)^2}{(2n)!}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for.